# PyQt5: How to display traceback(s) into a Widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, traceback, qplaintextedit

I which to display the errors into a `QPlainTextEdit` or any other **widget more suitable** for that.

**code.py**:

```py
import traceback
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(394, 185)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plntxt = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plntxt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 371, 131))
        self.plntxt.setObjectName("plntxt")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.m()
    def m(self):
        try:
            sdhfha #to create error that will be displayed to GUI
        except Exception as a:
            #I'm trying to pass the error named a into the PlainTextEdit
            self.plntxt.setPlainText(a)
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**the Error is:**

```py
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PySide2\???...

TypeError: setPlainText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NameError'
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the Exception to string:

```
def m(self):
    try:
        sdhfha
    except Exception as a:
        self.plntxt.setPlainText(str(a))
```